# Make String Array from Scanner InputStream

Tags: android, sql, arraylist, inputstream, java.util.scanner

I have a sql file and I reading that with this codes

```
 String text ="";
 InputStream is = mContext.getAssets().open("sample.sql"); 
 text = new Scanner( is,"UTF-8" ).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
```

I works perfect. it gives all string togetger but I want to make a Array devided by each next();